# How to set the repeat property of camunda timerEntity

Tags: camunda

I am using a Command to create a custom repeating Job for the camunda JobExecutor.

The api is

```
timerEntity.setRepeat(String repeat).
```

I tried ISO

```
timerEntity.setRepeat("PT25S");
```

and cron

```
timerEntity("*/25 * * * * *");
```

but in both cases I get a parse exception:

```
WARNING: Exception while excuting job 'TimerEntity[repeat*/15 * * * * *, id=1, revision=1, duedate=Mon Aug 24 22:34:46 CEST 2015, lockOwner=null, lockExpirationTime=null, executionId=null, processInstanceId=null, isExclusive=true, retries=3, jobHandlerType=DmnDirectoryWatcherJobHandler, jobHandlerConfiguration=null, exceptionByteArray=null, exceptionByteArrayId=null, exceptionMessage=null, deploymentId=null]':
Failed to parse cron expression: */15 * * * * *
```

Unfortunately, there is no suiting javaDoc on that method. In which format do I have to provide the repeat string to achieve an automatic reschedule every 25 seconds while the engine is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is written in the ISO8601 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Repeating_intervals), you should use R/PT25S for repeating intervals of 25 seconds.

Kind Regards, Ingo